# Search a value in Array of Observable

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm having array of Bool Observables in Rxswift.

```
let rxBoolObservableArray: [Observable<Bool>] = [Observable<Bool>]()
```

Now, How to get If any of the element is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `allSatisfy` extension based on @DanielT answer. It might be suitable for your problem:

```swift
extension Array where Iterator.Element: ObservableType {

    func allSatisfy(_ predicate: @escaping (Iterator.Element.E) throws -> Bool) -> Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(self) { try $0.allSatisfy(predicate) }
    }
}
```

example usage:

```swift
rxBoolObservableArray
    .allSatisfy { $0 } // { $0 == true }
    .subscribe(onNext: { areTestsPassing in
        print(areTestsPassing)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: I don't think the `rethrows` is necessary since Observables emit an error event rather than throwing.

Answer (score 2):

```
func containsFalse(array: [Observable<Bool>]) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(array) { $0.contains(false) }
}
```

The `combineLatest` function will subscribe to all the observables in the array.

The above will also update the array every time one of the observables updates its value so the output will always be correct. The accepted answer doesn't do that (it only works for the `Observable.just` function and is incorrect.)